# Comparing two dates in JavaScript but not working as I expected

Tags: javascript

I am comparing two date, one is the current date and the other is selected from the input  date type. I want if the selected date is less than the current date return true, but it does not returning true;

```
    function check_start_date(obj){


          var value= obj.value;
          var curr_date= new Date();
          var selected_date= new Date(value);
          curr_date= trim_time(curr_date);
          if(selected_date < curr_date){
               alert("less");
               return true;
           }
          else{
              return  false;
              }


    }
```

Comment: hard to say what's wrong without the actual values

Comment: What does           curr_date= trim_time(curr_date); do with the value?

Comment: @soulcheck 09/02/2014 It alerts true, if i select 09/15/2014 it return false. but when i select 09/14/2014(current date ) it again  alert less .

Comment: Dear @Pengtuzi 


function trim_time(obj){
obj.setFullYear(obj.getFullYear(),obj.getMonth(),obj.getDate());
obj.setHours(0);
obj.setMinutes(0);
obj.setSeconds(0);

return obj;

}

Answer (score 2):

Your `trim_time` function is not removing milliseconds, so the trimmed value `curr_date` will be slightly greater than `selected_date`, except when the current time falls exactly on the second (milliseconds is 0).

Answer (score 1):

I Changed My trim_time(obj) function and it did work :)

```
 function trim_time(obj){
     var obj1= new Date(obj.getFullYear(),obj.getMonth(),obj.getDate(),0,0,0);
    return obj1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution would be to use the `Number()` function. Then compare the two resulting numbers.

```
var curr_date = Number(new Date());

...

var selected_date = Number(new Date(value));

...
```

Then compare etc. Not tested btw, just some thoughts.

MDN explanation: [Number() Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)

Comment: You don't need to convert to numbers to be able to compare dates; operators like < > and == work fine on Date objects themselves. Also, if you did want raw numbers from the date objects for some reason, you could just use the getTime() function.

Comment: I don't disagree with you :), just something I would try if I was having problems with comparing dates.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the dates to numbers (for simple comparison). My solution would be:

```
function check_start_date( obj ) {
  var value = new Date( obj.value ) * 1; //--- convert to number
  var curr_date = new Date();
  curr_date = new Date( curr_date.getFullYear(), curr_date.getMonth(), curr_date.getDate()) * 1; //--- remove time from the date
  if( value < curr_ date ) {
    alert( 'less' );
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```